# Updating template after http call in Meteor

Tags: javascript, api, http, meteor

I'm making a new app with Meteor and I'm trying to get some public Github repos. I've written this call-method tuple:

```
Meteor.call('getRepositories', function(error, results) {
  console.log(results);
});

Meteor.methods({
  getRepositories: function(user) {
    var response = Meteor.http
      .call('GET','https://api.github.com/users/{username}/repos');
    return response.data;
  }
});
```

The problem is... how can I achieve to update the template with repositories names?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> // your_tmpl template 
> {{#each repos}}
>     {{name}} 
> {{/each}}
>
> // js template manager 
> var reactiveRepos = new ReactiveVar([]);
>
> Meteor.call('getRepositories', function(error, results) {  
>     reactiveRepos.set(results); 
> });
>
> Template.your_tmpl.helpers({
>     repos: function() {
>         return reactiveRepos.get();
>     } 
> });
>
> // server.js 
> Meteor.methods({   
>     getRepositories: function(user) {
>         var response = Meteor.http
>             .call('GET','https://api.github.com/users/{username}/repos');
>         return response.data; 
>     } 
> });
> ```

You could use ReactiveVar (http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivevar_pkg) package, that allow us to create reactive variables and use it in reactive environment, like helpers. Sure, you may want use it inside templates hooks as onRendered or onCreated for example, and bind it to your template.

Comment: +1 but better to use `reactiveRepos` var inside template, so it gets created when template is created and destroyed the same way